# Store email account's password

Tags: security, email-client, password-encryption

I'm developing an email client in PHP for IMAP accounts. Which would be the most secure way to store the account's password being able to retrieve it afterward to check emails?

I guess I should encrypt it somehow. However, how can I make sure that only my app will be able to decrypt it?

Comment: Research md5 one-way encryption

Comment: Do you need offline access (ie fetch mail when the user is not logged on)?

Comment: @jacktheripper: if the app needs to supply the user's password to the IMAP server, one-way encryption obviously won't be useful here. You need to be able to retrieve the actual password.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson not in the first stages, at least. However, I do need to be able to manage several accounts for the same user, so I can't be asking the user for each password on every login.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you require login without any user interactions, then there is no secure solution. You'll need to rely on your OS's storage options which might prevent hostile unprivileged applications from reading the password.

If the user entering a single password on startup is fine, then you can encrypt the other passwords with symmetric encryption, and then use a KDF, such as scrypt or PBKDF2 to derive the master key from the password (and a salt).

Answer (score 0):

Store the passwords in an encrypted file; require the decryption key when starting the app.